# How to cache YouTube for offline viewing in my app

Tags: android, youtube

I'm making a video watching app. I do NOT want to stream the videos. Is there a way to cache a YouTube video from the internet into my app (while on a wifi network) for offline viewing later (while without wifi)?

The reason would be so that I do not waste user's data plans.

Thanks. I know how to stream and how to download videos into Android apps, but I haven't found articles here on viewing offline caches.

Comment: I'd be really surprised if you were able to do this with YouTube because of licensing concerns. The YouTube app itself only lets you do this if you subscribe to their premium service.

Comment: you might be right Jeffrey